# How to call a non static method of an Activity from a C file

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have one `activity` that has one void method say `receiveSMS()`, this is a void method, because of some reason i can not make it static function.

my question is how to call a void method of `activity` from a `c` file.

as calling a non- static method we need the instance of the class. how can i get the instance of a `Activity` in my `c` file.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need the Following Signature for Void Type

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
```

after that add the method name with its package and its attribute 
as an example following can be use as reference

```
Java_com_putitout_buck_talkinganimals_VideoPlayback_setActivityPortraitMode(JNIEnv *, jobject, jboolean isPortrait)
{
    isActivityInPortraitMode = isPortrait;
}
```

in Java Method Signature will be like this

```
private native void setActivityPortraitMode(boolean isPortrait);
```

for further underStanding take look at [JNI](http://www.steveolyo.com/JNI/JNI.html)

Comment: my code for your reference JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Callbacks_nativeMethod(char* a, char * from) . i have global JAVAvm that i did while lodaing JNI , so i used global VM to get the env, and then class cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/natv/natt/XmppChatActivity");  XmppChatActivity is an Activity that contain the non static function . i need to call that function by using cls "(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mm, args);"  its needed obj , my question is how can i get obj (instance of An activity ) from c C file. Thanks In Advance